# SetOption for plotting

Tags: options, plot-themes

I want to change the default of [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) to use the scientific [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) with a grid

```
SetOptions[ListLinePlot, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", GridLines -> Automatic];
```

The [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLines.html) option does only work when given manually on the plots themselves or when not using `PlotTheme` in the [`SetOption`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOption.html) function. How do I stop `PlotTheme` from overwriting the `GridLines` option?

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/332/5478)

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78608

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80038/18476

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/332/18476

Comment: @Karsten7 Thank you very much; I see that my question was answered before. What I am still wondering is, if this behaviour can be assumed to be fixed? To me it seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the links given by Karsten 7 and reading around. I have the feeling that this [options configuration mananger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192599/create-functions-to-flexibly-define-chart-options-lists-in-mathematica/7197903#7197903) by Leonid Shiffrin best adresses my problem and gives more compatibility between packages. So I say thank you very much and close the question as answered.